# Magento-2 SOAP API can't create customer

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, soap

I am trying to create customer through SOAP API with below script. I am able to get customer details with customer id but can't create the customer.

I am getting this error "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'customer' property"

```
    <?php
    require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
    require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
    require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $request = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1/magento2011/soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1");
    //$token = $request->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken(array("username"=>"admin","password"=>"admin@123"));
    $token = $request->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken(array("username"=>"soapadmin","password"=>"admin@1234"));
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($token->result); exit;
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token->result
        )
    );
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($opts); exit;
    $serviceArgs = array("customerId" => 1);

    $customerparams = array('email' => 'customer-mail@example.org',
                            'firstname' => 'Dough',
                            'lastname' => 'Deeks',
                            'password' => 'test@123',
                            'website_id' => 1,
                            'store_id' => 1,
                            'group_id' => 1
                           );

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($customerparams); exit;

    $wsdlUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento2011/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1';
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    try{
        $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
        $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
        $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
        //$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById($serviceArgs);
        //$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetList();
        $soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1Save($customerparams);
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump((array) $soapResponse);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Exception Error:------".$e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Anyone please help on this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, Actually we need to pass parameters as like below format.

```
$customerdata = ['customer'=>
                                 [
                                  'email'=> 'customer-mail@example.org',
                                  'firstname' => 'Dough',
                                  'lastname' => 'Deeks',
                                  'password' => 'test@123',
                                  'promotion_code' => 'test123',
                                  'regulation' => '1',
                                  'website_id' => 1,
                                  'store_id' => 1,
                                  'group_id' => 1
                                 ]
                    ];
   $wsdlUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento2011/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1';
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    try{
        $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
        $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
        $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
        //$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById($customerId);
        //$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetList();
        $soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1Save($customerdata);
        //$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1DeleteById($serviceArgs);
        //$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetList($searchCriteria);
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump((array) $soapResponse);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Exception Error:------".$e->getMessage();
    }
```