# Need to fetch custom customer attribute load via SOAP API 'customerCustomerRepositoryV1'

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api

I used SOAP API `'{$baseUrl}soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1'` to get customer attributes values. I am successfully getting these attributes values like name, email etc all default values but i have not able to get custom customer attributes

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [extension attribute](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) concept for enable a custom attribute to API .

[How to use extension attributes for customer EAV attributes?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180937/how-to-use-extension-attributes-for-customer-eav-attributes)

Add this attribute as **extension attribute** **using extension_attribute.xml**. Create this file at your `app/code/{VendorName}/{Module}/etc` and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="{YOurAttributeCode}" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

*Type is depend on attribute type, if it is **a Varchar & text,multiselect** field, then use `string`. If it is **drop down,Yes/no then use as `interger`***.

Comment: Thanks @Amit for answer i would like to know one more thing i am using this script for create customer (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173722/magento-2-soap-api-cant-create-customer) & i need to add custom customer attribute data to it. How can i achieve this?